# Double tap selector fired multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

EDIT: I have this methods in an UIView placed on the top of multiple view controllers which are the "data source" of a UIPageViewController

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [tapGR setDelegate:self];
        [tapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
        [doubleTapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGR];

        [tapGR requireGestureRecognizerToFail :doubleTapGR];

        [tapGR release];
        [doubleTapGR release];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer{
    if (!(tapRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible)) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:kTapOnCenterNotificationName object:nil]];
    }
}

-(void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)doubleTapRecognizer{

    CGPoint point = [doubleTapRecognizer locationInView:self];

    LSSharedVariables *sharedVariables = [LSSharedVariables sharedInstance];
    [sharedVariables setDoubleTapPoint:point];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:kLongPressNotificationName object:nil]];

}
```

Even if I specified that the actions should be performed only if the gesture recognizer state is equal to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, the log is shown multiple times. I'd like to perform actions in this block only once, how should I do this?

EDIT: I figured out that the double tap method is called many times as much are the pages of the UIPageViewController. The thing I can't understand is why it isn't the same for the singleTapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Are you positive you haven't added the handleDoubleTap to multiple objects? It's possible they're all reporting that a doubleTap has occurred and are calling the method each independently. Do a search for "handleDoubleTap" just to verify that you aren't adding it multiple times.

Comment: You were right, multiple pages were observer for the sent notification and even if they aren't visible they were listening.

Comment: I'll add that comment as an answer then so we can get this question closed. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might have multiple objects listening for touches and all calling "handleDoubleTap" independently when it happens. That would explain why you're seeing it called multiple times when the double-tap event occurs.

I would start by searching through your code to verify that you're not adding it multiple times since the behavior you're experiencing isn't standard behavior for the touch events.

Comment: Actually there were multiple objects listening for the sent NSNotification, not for the double tap :) feel free to change your answer..

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) handleDoubleTap : (UIGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
NSLog (@"Double tap is being handled here");
}

- (void) handleSingleTap : (UIGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
NSLog (@"Single tap is being handled here");
}

- (void) loadView
{
UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self action : @selector (handleDoubleTap];
UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self action : @selector (handleSingleTap];

[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail : doubleTap];

[doubleTap setDelaysTouchesBegan : YES];
[singleTap setDelaysTouchesBegan : YES];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired : 2];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired : 1];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer : doubleTap];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer : singleTap];

[singleTap release];
[doubleTap release];
}
```

try this

Comment: It's very funny because I already have a different behavior for the single tap gesture! Anyway the double tap gesture is recognized multiple times..